# Misplaced navigation bar and question title

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, navigation

It appears that on Server Fault and Super User, the navigation bar and question title have suddenly become misplaced. The same does not occur on SO and mSO, nor on any of the other SE sites I spot-checked.

This is being seen in both Chrome and Firefox and just began occurring within the last few minutes.

[image: Misplaced elements on Server Fault]

[image: Misplaced elements on Super User]

What it should look like:

[image: Correctly placed elements on Stack Overflow]

---

While this was fixed for a few hours, it has returned as of 22:05.

Comment: Prob won't get much attention with no freehand circles.

Comment: @MDMarra This is a bit ... wide for a freehand _circle_. Perhaps a freehand _ellipse_?

Comment: @Michael You really do need some freehand circles. I had a hard time noticing what was wrong. Make sure they are red.

Comment: @Undo Fine, have some freehand ellipses...

Comment: Great! Now I can see the problem. They're red, too!

Comment: Also reproduced in FF21 and IE 9. Happens on SU and SF but not SO or MSO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some recent CSS changes caused this - a fix has been pushed out to the network.

All is well on Server Fault and Super User (at least as far as the header CSS is concerned).

Thanks for reporting.

Comment: It's back! As of 22:05:24.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - and fixed again a little later...

Answer (score 6):

Seems that in a recent change..

```
Last-Modified: Tue, 25 Jun 2013 02:19:21 GMT
```

..there are now two different widths doing battle for supremacy.  With 725 turned on, things are busted.

[image]

Comment: That's on Stack Overflow, too. The real difference is `padding-right` being 5px too large.

Comment: Er, `padding-left`, not `padding-right`.

Comment: @icktoofay Good catch.

Comment: Changing `width: 725px` to `width: 720px` fixes the issue for me.